# What does the square brackets in this initialization do in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, matrix, swift, scenekit

I am converting some Objective C code into Swift for `SceneKit` (line by line). I found this line of code in Objective-C and I cannot seem to figure out what it means.

```
SCNMatrix4 _cameraHandleTransforms[SLIDE_COUNT];
```

It comes from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SceneKitReel/Listings/SceneKitReel_AAPLGameViewController_m.html 
I understand it is creating a `SCNMatrix4` and I know that `SLIDE_COUNT` is a constant which resolves to `10`. I do not know what the square brackets do in this situation. I do not think there is any array access happening. Swift complains that it does not have subscript access for `SCNMatrix4` which makes sense when I check the Swift library.

Comment: Did you manually convert this code, or do so automatically?

Comment: @Riley I am reading Obj-C code and going line by line to convert into Swift. It comes from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SceneKitReel/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Do you know C, or any other common programming language???  That's an array!!

Comment: @HotLicks I never touched C. Just about everything else except C.

Comment: (If indeed you do not have a C background you really need to be using a tutorial (if there is one) that does not assume a C background.)

Comment: @HotLicks I'm a quick study. Just need to be informed. I had not seen Obj-C that initialized arrays in this way, yet. That would be because it is C. So of course in Java it would make sense but this isn't Java now is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a C-style statically-sized array declaration. This line declares a C array of type `SCNMatrix4` of size `SLIDE_COUNT`.

Swift is confused when you try to translate it, because it thinks you are trying to use subscript access on the type `SCNMatrix4`, which is a plain old C struct. See [the Apple docs on that type](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNMatrix4) for more detail, and remember:

**You can't have *Objective-C* without *C*!**

Answer (score 1):

It declares an array of SCNMatrix4 structures. The size of the array is SLIDE_COUNT.

Later on in that file (SceneKitReel/AAPLGameViewController.m) it accesses the various items from the _cameraHandleTransforms array. Look in the setupEnvironment and presentStep: methods.